# Use java version from registry in an autoit script

Tags: registry, autoit

This registry entry:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\4EA42A62D9304AC4784BF2381208370F]
>   "ProductName"="Java 8 Update 73"

I want to read this registry entry and output the product name `Java 8 Update 73` to a variable to be used in a function to see which version of Java is installed on a remote computer.

```
Local $JavaVersion = RegRead("HKLM ----?????
```

Won't the `CLSID` be different on each computer?

Comment: Why do you think CLSIDs differ between computers?

Answer (score 0):

The class ID remains the same on all computers. I would suggest getting the Java version installed from the following key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment

Like this:

```
Local $sJavaVersion = RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment", "CurrentVersion")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
But - it gave me an error = 0 and then output a value of 1.8

I can get the information from 2 separate keys but have to code double the information.

```
$jv = RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment","BrowserJavaVersion")
$jvv = RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment","CurrentVersion")
```